# Chrome 30 completely broken in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, google-chrome

I just installed chrome from the deb file (64 bit) and it is completely broken! Almost every page gives basic javascript errors, the window freezes every few minutes, there are lots of visual glitches when reordering tabs, and in most pages the page name does not appear in the tab.

Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Where did you obtained that deb file? Why you haven't installed chromium or chrome from PPA via apt-get?

Comment: Got it from official download page

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling it (`dpkg -r chrome`), and re-installing from official PPA instead: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome ?

Comment: Why install Chrome by hand when Chromium is packaged? Are you aware of the differences [1] between the two? [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome on 14.04. Which I installed using `apt-get`. Had to switch to Firefox. What I do not understand is that Chrome was working fine, and one day suddenly for me, it just became unusable (the main problem being that the screen does not render properly).

Answer (score 0):

**Delete the Chrome Profile folder.**

1 - Open your Home folder

2 - Press **CTRL** & **H** to show the hidden folders

3 - Click on the folder named **.config**

4 - Right click on the folder named **google-chrome** and delete it.

Now restart Google Chrome and see if the problem persists.

Deleting the profile folder just resets Chrome as if it's a new install.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping to remove Chrome, you'll need to call it by its specific name or else you'll get the error *dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove google-chrome which isn't installed*

e.g. use: `dpkg -r chrome` or `dpkg -r google-chrome`

For me, I used

```
dpkg -r google-chrome-stable
```

You can confirm the name of your installed package with

```
dpkg --get-selections|grep chrome
```

and it took it away like a charm. Use the answer from @scouser73 to make sure the .config files are deleted as well.